# Triggering styles that apply with a different selector, via media queries

Tags: css

The code I have is as follows:
 there is one HTML that have two views, a list view and a card view and the user can choose whichever he/she prefers. when the user clicks card view I add a class card view to a parent element and I trigger css for that selector for example **list view** will be `.order{}` card view will be `.card_view .order{}` now I want to make that when mobile (with media queries) it should only apply the card view.

If someone can help I'll appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: At least you could put the whole list view part of the CSS inside a media query for larger screens.

Comment: Grait! I'll try it, I think its a good idea

Comment: no, it does not work because the card view styles does not apply (nor list view, you could imagine how it looks)

Comment: Then you’re just doing it wrong … Make your card view the _default_ style (applied without an additional class on the parent), and outside of the media query. Then set up your formatting for the list view, with that additional class on the parent, inside the media query that targets large enough screens only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.order,
.card_view {
    /* same properties for both CSS selectors - both will look the same */
    color: white;
    background-color: #ddd;
}    
@media( min-width: 480px ) {
    .order {
       /* override styles for larger screens for this CSS selector - different looks */
       color: red;
    }
}
```

Any viewport less than 480px wide would use the same styles for `.order` and `.card_view` since they have the same definition. At 480px and above, `.order` would use the re-defined styles in the media query and they now have different definitions and will be styled differently.

Comment: But then I don't have an option when big screen to select between list and card, the way I did it currently is to place in card view when the user chooses

Comment: You can switch between the two at larger screen sizes. `.order` is `.order { color: red; background-color: #ddd; }` and `.card_view` is `.card_view { color: white; background-color: #ddd; }` for larger screens.

Comment: @daveguru [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/p0rmewLo/), click the buttons at various screen sizes.